# Additional index in shard collection in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, indexing, sharding

I have sharded collection with shard key as hashed **_id** ([docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-hashed-index/) ).

Now I want to add index on another field (called **alias**) which doesn't need to be unique but it should be sparse if possible. This new index would serve only for speeding my query.

Should I do some kind of compound index for this or there is another procedure if possible in the first place?

In app I make only 2 types of queries :

```
db.myCollection.findOne({alias : 'some-alias'})
db.myCollection.findOne({_id : 'some-id'})
```

The second one works as supposed to (because my shard key is on hashed _id field) but first query is problem.

Thanks,
Ivan

Comment: What do your queries look like? Can you show an example? Do you use the shard key in an exact match in your queries?

Comment: I have updated my question. So I don't use shard key in queries except that I sometimes make query on _id field which works as supposed to.

Comment: OK, then just make an index on `{ "alias" : 1 }` with `{ "sparse" : true }` option: `db.myCollection.ensureIndex({ "alias" : 1 }, { "sparse" : true })`. Make sure you create the index on mongos so it's created the same on all the shards.